# C# if condition that trigger if item is inactive in hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple script that displays a UI prompt and disappears when you exit the collider I wrote and if statement that also disables the text if the item is inactive because when the player picks up the item, the item is set to inactive but the UI element still lingers.

```
public Text PickUpText;

void Update()
{
    if (!gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        PickUpText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        PickUpText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        PickUpText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update method will not be called if gameobject is not active. You need to use **OnDisable** method.

```
public Text PickUpText;

void OnDisable()
{
    PickUpText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        PickUpText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        PickUpText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `OnDisable()` if you want to call your code when object gets disabled. `Update()` method is not called on disabled objects.

Comment: Keep in mind you don't have to check if gameObject is disabled in the OnDisable() method. This method is called only when the object gets disabled.